# Hyphenate 'part-time' / 'full-time' as an adverb?

Tags: punctuation

Would we hyphenate 'part-time' / 'full-time' as an adverb?

*1. Joe worked part-time as a waiter and full-time as a computer programmer.* (Can we omit the hyphens in these adverbial uses?)

*2. Mike said, "Joe is part-time."* (Meaning Joe is a part-time associate. Should we keep the hyphen in this construction?)

*3. Joe is a part-timer.* (Meaning that Joe is an associate who works part time. Should we keep the hyphen in "part-timer"?)

Answer (score 3):

In my view the hyphen is not essential in any of the three examples you have given. But if used as a compound adjective before the noun it qualifies it definitely needs, in my opinion to be hyphenated, e.g.

'The club decided to appoint a part-time cook.'

Comment: Collins agrees: **part-time** — adj
1. for less than the entire time appropriate to [/often devoted to] an activity: _a part-time job_ ; _a part-time waitress_
 
— adv 2. on a part-time basis: _he works part time_.
 
And gives, as do some other authorities, only the hyphenated version of the (agent) compound noun: **part-timer** — n